# Isolation Level - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, ambiente

Opa

Tenho um ambiente OLAP onde há relatórios que consome informações do mesmo. Porém ultimamente tenho pegado alguns LOCKS no ambiente por algumas procs antigas não estarem "devidamente" elaboradas.

Sei que o aplicando READ UNCOMMITED e WITH(NOLOCK) nas PROCS onde as mesmas estão sendo utilizadas , o problema de concorrência ira diminuir.

Sabendo que o ISOLATION LEVEL esta setado por DEFAULT ( SQL SERVER ) , há algum risco de eu setar ele como ON em ambiente produtivo ?

Para as procedures que estão nos relatórios, há alguma opção de ISOLATION level mais adquado para eles ? Sabendo que os mesmos consumem informações já carregadas ?

E há possibilidade de eu encontrar uma situação em que a PROC esta em READ_COMMITED e ter tabelas usando o hint WITH(NOLOCK) ?

Estou usando o SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: Mas você colocar em seus relatórios dados de transações ainda não commitadas não é temerário?

Comment: @Anonimo neste caso eu teria que assumir que todas as minhas Procs que alimentam meu ambiente OLAP estariam usando um BEGIN TRAN certo ?

Comment: Quaisquer modificações, sejam inserções ou alterações, deveriam estar em transações. Mas eu só posso chutar pois não conheço seu modelo de dados ou sua forma de processamento. Como você fala em LOCKS presume-se que sejam consequência de transações não finalizadas.

Comment: @anonimo Mas o BEGIN TRAN tanto para INSERT UPDATE ? Porque comecei a adminstrar um ambiente meio bagunçado , consegui notar que tem 197 procs sem estar com o HINT WITH(NOLOCK) , porém estar com o NOLOCK não é certeza que esta em melhores praticas ... certo?

Comment: *"há algum risco de eu setar ele como ON em ambiente produtivo"*, não há um "ON", você deve setar o nível desejado. Suas perguntas são difíceis de responder, por exemplo *"Para as procedures que estão nos relatórios, há alguma opção de ISOLATION level mais adquado "*, depende, tem que ver o que a procedure faz e seu objetivo, além de ter muitas dúvidas diferentes, talvez consiga melhores respostas se fizer mais de uma pergunta, cada uma mais específica